# How is Uposatha practiced in non Buddhist countries?

Tags: traditions, holidays

Uposatha (a.k.a. Poya Day) is the traditional Buddhist observance day. Observances vary but one traditional pattern is to celebrate this day on the lunar calendar on each of four moon events; the new moon, full moon, and quarter moons.

For those living in traditional Buddhist countries or communities, there may be opportunities to visit a monastery. But how do those in non Buddhist countries celebrate the holiday?

Comment: Happy Uposatha Day! You "stole" my question. I was going to ask if any western forms of Buddhism have established any westernized customs.

Comment: Sorry for that @MatthewMartin. Happy Uposatha to you as well. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uposatha day is the day when the vinaya is recited. The vinaya is of course the list of all the rules that monastics follow.

In Asia, there are well defined community practices. For example, people go to the local temple that day, or in Mahayana Buddhism, you might fast (i.e. eat vegetarian) that day, or make a stronger effort to follow the five precepts or maybe follow all [8 precepts](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/uposatha.html).

Out here in the west, not a lot of community practices visible to me. I personally try to make up for it by re-reading my favorite list of rules, the "Brahma Net Sutra" on Uposatha days, which is the same thing that real life east Asian Buddhist monks do.

I suppose a lay follower who wants to keep to the spirit of the holiday, but didn't want to read or recite a particular moral code, might do a sort of "Weekly Review" like you see in system of personal productivity, except with a Buddhist theme, e.g. http://lifehacker.com/5908816/the-weekly-review-how-one-hour-can-save-you-a-weeks-worth-of-hassle-and-headache